# Didn't get the correct x y value in onTouch

Tags: android

I want to move an image when I drag on the screen, but the x and y values in ACTION_MOVE are not correct. I have printed the x and y value in ACTION_MOVE. In each alternate it prints the correct x and y value.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
  float x=0;
  float y=0;

  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

     break;

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

     break;


  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      x=event.getX();
      y=event.getY();
      System.out.println("x= "+x+" y="+y);
      int width = 100, height = 100;
      lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, (int) (x), (int) (y));

    break;
  }
  mLayout.updateViewLayout(view, lp);

  return true;
 }
```

This is my code. And printed output is:

```
01-17 10:31:11.721: I/System.out(3983): x= 71.0 y=91.0
01-17 10:31:11.746: I/System.out(3983): x= 102.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:11.776: I/System.out(3983): x= 72.0 y=91.0
01-17 10:31:11.806: I/System.out(3983): x= 103.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:11.826: I/System.out(3983): x= 73.0 y=91.0
01-17 10:31:11.851: I/System.out(3983): x= 104.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:11.871: I/System.out(3983): x= 74.0 y=91.0
01-17 10:31:11.896: I/System.out(3983): x= 105.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:11.921: I/System.out(3983): x= 75.0 y=91.0
01-17 10:31:11.941: I/System.out(3983): x= 107.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:11.957: I/System.out(3983): x= 76.0 y=90.0
01-17 10:31:11.976: I/System.out(3983): x= 109.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:11.996: I/System.out(3983): x= 77.0 y=90.0
01-17 10:31:12.026: I/System.out(3983): x= 110.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:12.056: I/System.out(3983): x= 78.0 y=90.0
01-17 10:31:12.101: I/System.out(3983): x= 111.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:12.131: I/System.out(3983): x= 79.0 y=89.0
01-17 10:31:12.186: I/System.out(3983): x= 112.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:12.231: I/System.out(3983): x= 80.0 y=89.0
01-17 10:31:12.276: I/System.out(3983): x= 113.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:12.296: I/System.out(3983): x= 80.0 y=88.0
01-17 10:31:12.316: I/System.out(3983): x= 114.0 y=24.0
01-17 10:31:12.336: I/System.out(3983): x= 81.0 y=88.0
```

The alternate points are correct. But how is it happening? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You say the x and y are not correct, then you say "The alternate points are correct." ?? So is it correct or incorrect? Make up your mind before asking :)

Comment: This is the output when I dragged on the screen from x-coordinate 102 to 114. But some other values are coming alternatively

Comment: Problem solved.... I have added touch listener to the view. It is redrawing in every moment. I have added touch listener to the layout. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609114/android-beginner-understanding-motionevent-actions), he says that Views can have a built-in touch event which might be interfering with your touch event. Check if your view has one.

Comment: Problem solved.... I have added touch listener to the view. It is redrawing in every moment. I have added touch listener to the layout. Thank you